# If your employer tells you "we will push your rate up to $40 an hour" does it mean they will push it to exactly $40/hr?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

I am confused if that sentence means exactly $40/hr or just up to $40/hr in which case the rate could become $35/hr for example.

Comment: Most likely so, but there is an interpretation where they plan to push your rate up in steps, ending with 40. So 38, then 40 after another year.

Comment: The verb here is _push [something] up_, with the target indicated by the preposition _to_. It’s not the compound preposition _up to_ meaning ‘increasing to a limit no higher than’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take that to mean exactly 40/hr.

Otherwise wd say something like "we will push up your rate to as much as 40/hr"

Comment: Hi Micah, thanks for your contribution but please note this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: we're not a forum for sharing personal opinions. Instead, an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. See the [comment by Janus](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/478622/#comment1155481_478622) for the kind of explanation we're looking for. (PS - you're allowed to adapt his comment and add it to your answer!). :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an ambiguity here, but it has more to do with the word *push*, then with the prepositions *up to*. If the person said 'we will raise your rate (up) to $40 an hour', there would be no ambiguity: we would expect the new rate to be exactly $40 an hour. The choice of the word *push* can, however, be taken to imply that raising the rate will require some effort, that there may be some resistance to it. Perhaps the person wants to convey that the managers of the relevant department ('we') will try to raise the rate all the way to that amount, but that the higher-ups will resist it; the result of the 'pushing' between the two groups could then turn out to be the new rate of, say, $35 an hour.

If the person who said this is somebody who chooses words very carefully, it is possible that there was some such implication here. It is, however, also possible that the person chose the word *push* without thinking too much about its nuances; after all, the quick flow of workplace interactions is very different from the leisurely pace of careful analysis that is practised on this site. The only way to find out what the person really had in mind is to ask him or her.